# Monitor deploy progress on AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I have AWS Amplify to automatically pull my Github repository/branch. Where are the build logs? I don't have any errors yet but want to see when builds succeed or not. Also, is there a build history somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step-by-step to see the build history:**

1. Go to your Amplify console
2. Click your application
3. In your "Frontend environments" tab, click your branch name (e.g. `master`)
4. At the bottom in your left bar, click "History" menu
5. You can see the build history

**The direct link to the history:**

`https://[region-name].console.aws.amazon.com/amplify/home?region=[region-name]#/[app-id]/[branch-name]/history`

Example for region `ap-southeast-1` and branch `master`:

`https://ap-southeast-1.console.aws.amazon.com/amplify/home?region=ap-southeast-1#/c2bfvukzh9fuh2/master/history`

Comment: I just assumed that highlighted title was the same as the image link and was going to take me to the app. Thx.